# ADM Device could not be created because of "incompatible JDK"

Tags: java, android, openjdk-11, maui, android-device-manager

Android Device Manager prevents me from creating an Android Device because of an incompatible JDK. However, maui-check shows me that i've got OpenJDK 11.0 installed.

[Image of error message and maui-check.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwMjf.png)

[Image of device I'm trying to create.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHyQ6.png)

I've tried the "Install and configure Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK" but going through that it just shows me that everything is installed correctly.

[Image of JDK install confirmation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGwiC.png)

What exactly am I missing here, do I have to install a previous version of the JDK?

Comment: Could you check the Visual Studio Installer under the Individual Components tab, then Emulators if the Google Android Emulator (API Level 25) (local install) checkbox is checked?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis It wasn't checked yet, I checked it, installed it, but it still shows the same problem, do I have to configure it somewhere? Could it be because I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Preview?

Comment: Welp, Tried making a device starting the device manager from visual studio 2019, that seemed to work instantly. I guess vs2022 preview isn't done far enough for that yet, thanks for the help though!

Comment: Weird! Should work just as well for VS2022, it does for me.. Glad you figured something out though!

Answer (score 3):

Download OpenJDK 8.0.41 from [here](https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8u41/ri/openjdk-8u41-b04-windows-i586-14_jan_2020.zip)

Unzipped files in **Program Files > JDK > OpenJDK_8.0.41**

Update JDK location in Visual Studio 2022, go to Tools > Xamarin > set above folder path in **Java Development Kit Location**

[Original solution](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/loading-Android-virtual-device-in-device/1154493#T-N1154512)